# Test of Hypothesis with Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability, computational-mathematics, hypothesis-testing

It is known that 40% of a certain species of birds have characteristic B. Twelve birds of this species are captured in an unusual environment and 4 of them are found to have characteristic B.

Is it reasonable to assume that the birds in this environment have a smaller probability than that the species in general has?

> I assumed that this is a binomial case with $p=0.4$ and $n=12.$ Then to figure out if the assumption of the birds having smaller probability than the species is correct, I tried to do it using hypothesis testing and finding the P-value, but I got confused. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Well, under the null hypothesis the probability that you'd see at most $4$ type B birds is $0.438178222$...the probability that you'd see exactly $4$ is $0.21284094$ so I don't see how you could reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: Not reasonable because your sample has 4 whereas the expected value is 3, so this is hardly evidence that this sample has fewer than expected.

Answer (score 8):

**Null and Alternative Hypotheses.** You want to test $H_0: p = .4$ against $H_a: p < .4.$

In $n = 12$ observations you observe $X = 4$ birds of Type B.
If the null hypothesis is true $E(X) = np = 12(.4) = 4.8.$

While it is true that you observed fewer than the 'expected'
number of birds of Type B, the question is whether 4 is *enough*
smaller than 4.8 to reject $H_0,$ calling this a 'statistically
significant' result.

**Finding the P-value.** The P-value is the probability (assuming $H_0$ to be true) 
of a result as extreme or more
extreme (in the direction of the alternative) than the 
observed $X = 4.$

If $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 12,\, p = .4),$ then the P-value is
$P(X \le 4) = 0.4382.$

This can be computed with a calculator using the PDF of
 $\mathsf{Binom}(12, .4),$ and evaluating
$P(X \le 4) = P(X=0) + P(X=1) + \cdots + P(X=4),$
or by using software. The computation in R statistical
software is as follows:

```
pbinom(4, 12, .4)
## 0.4381782
```

**Conclusion.** So the P-value of the test is about 0.44, which is not
surprisingly small. Testing at the 5% level of significance,
one would not reject $H_0$ unless the P-value is less than 0.05.
Thus, seeing 4 birds of Type B is consistent with $H_0$ by
the usual standards of statistical significance. (This is the same as
the conclusion in the Comments of @lulu and @DavidQuinn, even if perhaps
not for precisely the same reasons.)

---

**P-value by Normal Approximation.** Alternatively, an approximate value of this probability can be found by using the
normal approximation to the binomial distribution (with continuity correction):
$\mu = E(X) = 4.8,$ as above, and $\sigma = SD(X) = \sqrt{np(1-p)} = 1.6971.$
Then the 'best-fitting' normal distribution is 
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 4.8, \sigma =  1.6971).$ The approximation is
as follows:

$$P(X \le 4.5) = P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \le 
\frac{4.5-4.8}{1.6971} = -0.1768\right) \approx P(Z \le -0.18) = 0.4286,$$

where $Z$ has a standard normal distribution, so that the approximate probability
can be found using printed normal tables. Slightly more accurately (without rounding to use tables), the normal approximation of the P-value can
be found using software:

```
n = 12;  p = .4;  mu = n*p; sg = sqrt(n*p*(1-p))
pnorm(4.5, mu, sg)
## 0.4298419
```

---

**Sketch of Null Binomial Distribution.** Below is a plot of 
$\mathsf{Binom}(12, .4)$ (black bars) compared with the PDF of the 'best fitting'
normal distribution (blue curve). The P-value is the sum of the heights of the bars
to the left of the vertical red line.

[image]

Comment: @Pawalek: The 'continuity correction' for normal aprx. calls for using 4.5 instead of 4.0. Using 4.0 would lead to inaccurate computation `pnorm((4-4.8)/1.6971)`, which returns 0.3186803 (rather far from exact 0.4381782, and not a good as approx 0.4298419). In any case this is not an ideal situation for normal approx: n = 12 is too small.

Comment: I was under the impression that the normal approximation to the binomial distribution can only be used when np and n(1-p) are both sufficiently large (both greater than 5). Here, np=12(0.4) = 4.8 and n(1-p)=12(0.6)=7.2, so I don't think the normal approximation to the binomial distribution can be used here. What do you think?

Comment: @StatsSorceress. Already noted that $n=12$ is a bit too small. The "rule" that $\min(np,n(1-p))\ge 5$ (or $4$ or $10$ or whatever) is only a rough guide. If $p$ is near $1/2,$ sometimes normal approximation with continuity correction works OK, even if 'rule' violated. Example: If $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(3, 1/2),$ then $P(X \le 1) = 1/2$ exactly, and norm aprx w/ cc gives $P(X\le 1) = P(X\le 1.5) = .5000.$

Comment: Thanks @BruceET!